# C# Passing data through forms

Tags: c#, winforms

Tried to find a solution for this problem, but couldn't find working one so I decided to question it myself.

I have a textbox in Form2.cs named "ipaddress_2" , and one in Form1.cs named "ipaddress".

This is the code that i use to launch Form2.cs.

```
    private void rtmTool_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

I want to import the data from Form2.cs box to Forms1.cs ip box so when the user has closed the form2.cs , form1 will have the (form2) ip already filled in.

This is the link for form1.cs if you need/want to take a look.
http://www.mediafire.com/download/3f5726axo7w6o92/Source.txt

Regards.

Comment: did u try Form1 constructor and again call form1?, pass ipaddress as an argument when initializing Form1 on form2 closing button!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, in `Form2.Designer.cs` file, the `ipaddress_2` is declared as `private`. Change the access specifier to `public`.

Then from `Form1.cs`, you can access the `Form2.cs - ipaddress_2` control as following.

```
private void rtmTool_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.ShowDialog();
    ipAddress.Text = f2.ip_address2.Text; // After the Form2.cs has been closed, the ipaddress from Form2.cs has been accessed and displayed in Form1.cs - ipaddress Textbox.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When f2 is closed, control will return to the function which called ShowDialog.

f2 will still be available to use, so as long as the controls are declared as public, you should be able to access them directly:

```
private void rtmTool_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.ShowDialog();
    ipAddress.Text = f2.ip_address2.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the other two answers, my view is that a control should not be made public unless you have a very valid reason to....in cases like this i usually prefer to keep my controls private add properties that read the controls only. See my example below

### Form 1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(var form = new Form2())
        {
            form.ShowDialog();
            ipAddess.Text = form.IpAddress;
        }
    }
}
```

### Form 2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string IpAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return ip_address.Text;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating an object(s) to hold any data that you want to display on the forms and pass this object from the first form to the second. The object can then be bound to the controls of both the forms and will propagate its data across the two.

Sample object

```
    public class IPSettings:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string ipAddress;

    public string IPAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ipAddress;
        }
        set
        {
            this.ipAddress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IPAddress");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if(handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Form 1

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ipSettings = new IPSettings();
        textBoxIpAddress1.DataBindings.Add("Text", ipSettings, "IPAddress");
    }

    private IPSettings ipSettings;

    private void buttonOpenDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form2(ipSettings).ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Form 2

```
    public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2(IPSettings ipSettings)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBoxIpAddress2.DataBindings.Add("Text", ipSettings, "IPAddress",false,DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
    }
}
```